# Django logout not working - can't understand why

Tags: python, django

Hi guys hope someone can help me here. I am just starting to create a simple web app using django and I am confused why this isn't working.

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout

def index(request):
    return render(request, "fittracker/main.html")
def login_view(request):
    pass
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("fittracker/main.html")
def signup(request):
    pass
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path("logout/", views.logout, name='logout')
]
```

I am getting this error
[image: logout error]

I have tired looking at the official docs, and this should redirect, but I am not sure why it isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the view is `logout_view`, so it hould be `views.logout_view`:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout')
]
```

Now you use the `logout` that you *re-exported* from the `django.contrib.auth` module.

Comment: Yep that worked, this what happens when you code without enough coffee

Answer (score 0):

Also, just for the readers after Nov 2023.
From your template, you cannot do:

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}>Logout</a> #won't work
```

GET method for /logout has been deprecated. [check here](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/deprecation-of-get-method-for-logoutview/25533)

**New Implementation:**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">logout</button>
 </form>
```